# Having only one default value in model with django ORM

Tags: python, django, database-design, orm

I want to have only one default value in Django model.

I have a model:

```
@with_author  
class MaterialManufacture(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.PROTECT,  related_name = 'material')
    manufacture = models.ForeignKey(Manufacture, on_delete=models.PROTECT,  related_name = 'manufacture')
    materialmanuf_status = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                              choices=MANUF_STATUS_CHOICES)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % ( self.id, self.code, self.name)
```

And the choices for this model are

```
MANUF_STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('D','Default'),
    ('A','Additional'),
)
```

I just want to have only one default option from MANUF_STATUS_CHOICES per each unique combination of my Foreign keys? Is it possible to do with some Django built in options or some smart database design or I have to implement it in the view when I  save ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "only one default value", but I think what you're trying to do is this: if a value for a field isn't explicitly set by the user, set it to a default value based on the value of some other fields of the same model. If that's right, then the standard way to do this is to override the model's `save()` method.

Comment: sorry if I am not clear , the goal is to have default value only once. Example: FK Good  and FK steak is made from beef so beef the only default value for steak  however there additional options as pork, chicken, turkey  and you can add unlimited amount of those additional options when the default is only one -beef.

Comment: I am thinking now to make the first value added automatically to be always  default and all the coming after to be added as additional however  in order to change default to create  a separate interface with radio buttons.